# Record and return onClick events

Tags: javascript, html

I have used onClick events to manipulate the current time of a video in previous programs, but I am wondering if there is a way for me to record the onClick events and return each value.

Specifically, I have a 15 minute video playing, and I want to record each time a participant clicks a specific button, and return each time they click.

Is this even possible? I would prefer that the information returns in a txt file, however even if they all just return to the page I would be content with that.

edit: Here is the current code I have. My experience in JS (in use of HTML) is quite limited and this is a basically the extent of my current understanding. The issue that I'm having is that I do not want to use an alert window, and instead need to be able to record every time the participant clicks the "get" button in a manner that is invisible to them, yet I am able to record after their interaction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--Video-->
<video id = "15min" style="width:740px; height:440px" controls autoplay>
    <source src="C:\Users\Theresa\Desktop\vigilclipped.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<!--Video Jump functions-->
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("15min");

    function setCurTime() {
        vid.currentTime = 500;
    }
</script>
<script>

var vid = document.getElementById("15min");

    function getCurTime() {
        alert(vid.currentTime);
    }
 </script>

<!--Buttons-->
<button onClick="setCurTime()">
Set
</button>
<button onClick="getCurTime()">
Get
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show some code for it?

Comment: Why would it not be possible? Try to bind your events, record them in memory or cache or cookies or send them to the server, maybe along with a session id. To export, I'm sure you can send the data to the server and write it to a text file or do what ever your requirement states.